# What do link editor (LD) params mean?

Tags: makefile, linker, gnu-make, linker-flags

I write NASM (netwide assembler) program and for some reasons I needed to use some functions written in C. So, I tried to link compiled C object files with compiled Assembly objects using ***ld*** link editor. I did it by this way :

`ld -m elf_x86_64 -lc --dynamic-linker=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2   object_files -o program`.

And it didn't want to link and work long enough until I picked up the necessary parameters. Now this works as expected with this parameter set. But I don't understand the meaning of `-lc` and `--dynamic-linker=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. What do they do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. -lc - link c standard library
2. --dynamic-linker=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2.  - set the program loader. Linux ELF binaries have a field for this.

Afaik the latter is needed even for static binaries, anything other will confuse the loader, and it won't execute.

man ld lists its parameters.